# Analysis True or False Question. (Simple)

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

First one, I think it's true just by definition.

Second one, I think it's true as well.

Third one, i dont think sinx = cosx in interval [0,pi/2].

Am i missing anything?
If there are counterexamples that I simply ignored, please tell me.

Thank yOu

Comment: Here's a good way to make sure you haven't ignored any counterexamples: give a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third one is also true, by the intermediate value theorem. Consider $f(x)=\sin x - \cos x$ on $[0,\pi/2]$. We easily see $f(0)=-1$ and $f(\pi/2)=1$, so there must exist a point $p\in [0,\pi/2]$ with $f(p)=0$. Then $\cos p = \sin p$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for the third one take $g(x)=\sin x-\cos x$   find $g(0),g(\pi/2)$

Answer (score 1):

1) is not "true just by definition", it's a theorem (sum and difference of functions continuous at $c$ are continuous at $c$).

3) Have you looked at the graphs of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$?

Comment: right theorem 2. something from my book!
I just read it Thank you rob!